# How can I rearrange android non-english string.xml follow to english string.xml files sorting by name

Tags: android, sorting, android-studio, string.xml

I want to rearrange string tags in non-english string.xml file to follow the english version string.xml file. I know android studio has reformat code feature that will reformat by customization pattern, but I need to follow format as english version string.xml. Have we have any trick to do like this.

for example

in string.xml english version

```
<string name="game.name">name</string>
<string name="game.mobile.number">mobilenumber</string>
<string name="game.mobile.type">mobilenumber</string>
```

string.xml non-english version

```
<string name="game.mobile.type">ชนิดโทรศัพท์</string>
<string name="game.mobile.number">หมายเลขโทรศัพท์</string>
<string name="game.name">ชื่อ</string>
```

that if follow string.xml in english version, "game.name" should be first line.

Comment: Can you explain more with any example?

Comment: I already added an example on question.